# actionscript 3, action after multiple tweening done

Tags: actionscript

I am a newbie in game developing, now i am working with a shooter game for learning purpose.
I have a question,

in my game I created three tween animation :

```
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(this, "scaleX", Back.easeIn, 1.2, 0, 10);
var myTween2:Tween = new Tween(this, "scaleY", Back.easeIn, 1.2, 0, 10);
var myTween3:Tween = new Tween(this, "alpha", None.easeIn, 1, 0, 10);
```

This tweens will occur after enemy's health become zero,
What I intended is after the animation, the clip will be removed from stage.

my question is, is there a way to know that all these tweens has finished? I tried to apply TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH event for each tween , but If i do that i have to create three listenesr ( which will be problematic if I want to create ten tweens).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since all the tweens run for the same duration could you not just add your listener to the last tween and when the handler executes you will know that they have all completed?

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import fl.motion.easing.Back;
import fl.transitions.easing.None;

// Populate an array with the tweens
var tweens:Array = [];
tweens.push(new Tween(this, "scaleX", Back.easeIn, 1.2, 0, 10));
tweens.push(new Tween(this, "scaleY", Back.easeIn, 1.2, 0, 10));
tweens.push(new Tween(this, "alpha", None.easeIn, 1, 0, 10));

// Finished tweens count
var finishedCount:int = 0;

// Loop through all the tweens and add a handler for the motion finished event
for (var i:int = 0; i < tweens.length; i ++)
{
    // Each of the tweens motion finished event can be assigned to the same handler
    Tween(tweens[i]).addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, motionFinishedHandler);
}

function motionFinishedHandler(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    // Good practice to remove the event listener when it is no longer needed
    e.target.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, motionFinishedHandler);

    // Increment the count and test whether it equals the number of tweens
    if (++ finishedCount == tweens.length)
        trace("Finished");
}
```

You might also want to consider [Greensock's TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) which is pretty much the standard for animating objects in Flash and which will allow you to tween multiple properties of the same object in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

**+1 for Greensock's TweenLite & TimelineLite.**

Makes tweening everything cleaner and easier.